# Hide overflow inside div content from left side when browser resize in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have read all the SO question and do google but can't answer. I have a bootstrap layout and I need when browser resize content to hide from both side (left and right).

- If I use `overflow-x:hidden` then it's hidden from right only
- If I give margin in negative then layout goes wrong

As you see in code. When browser resizes only right side image hide. But I need that page hide from both sides. I need only CSS solution please.

```css
body {
   overflow-x:hidden;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 -585px;
  position:relative; 
  left:50%
}
.left-img {
  width: 600px;
  height: 700px;
 }
.right-img {
  width: 700px;
  height: 600px;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/w3images/lights.jpg" class="img-responsive left-img">
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/w3images/lights.jpg" class="img-responsive right-img">
   </div>

</div><!-- end wrapper-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your wrapper and it will work. I don't know if it's the best solution but it works because it must overflow of the left screen there must be set margin to a negative number (half of the wrapper width).

[Live example](https://jsfiddle.net/6q6udk1t/2/)

```
.wrapper {
   width:1270px;
   margin:0 auto 0 -635px; 
   position:relative; 
   left:50% 
}
```

I think, there could be a problem on small screens. But you have an example how to do it and some specific screens you can target by media queries.

Comment: From my example I deleted `overflow-x: hidden;` it works